# Shopify / Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm drawing specific polygons within Google's Earth Engine, and then hoping to show those images of the polygon on my Shopify store.  The javascript code that is presented in Google's Earth Engine code editor, I hope to be able to pasted into Shopify and then the image surfaces.

Is this possible?

I'm trying to build a library of features on the earth that I will then "service" with a special type of landscape service.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  You had tags for multiple products but make no mention of how they relate to your question and so I have deleted them.

Comment: It is also possible with Leaflet - https://leafletjs.com/examples.html